# Horizontal scroll to next element inside a container prevent standard scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I have got a Facebook news feed to display inline in an endless horizontal scrolling container which should only scroll between the news elements and prevent the default continuous scrolling behaviour.

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wgLdeLnv/1/)

This code entered manually already focuses (not exactly) on the specific news, eg. focusedNews = 1 -> first news-container is focused. Because i know every container has a width of 500px and i animate the parent containers position, to move the wanted element into the focus.

```
 $(".fbNews").animate({left: -(focusedNews - 1) * 500}, 500);
```

Firstly i detect in which direction the user scrolls which works and logs the direction to the console. Then i either add or subtract 1 to the focusedNews Index but the scroll event happens way more often than once. I thought of _.debounce or _.throttle the scroll event, but that didn't help.

How can i animate to the next or previous element on scroll and prevent the default behaviour?

I use the fullpageJS library for such effects on vertical scroll and horizontal slides in other projects, but the library only works for full pages and not inside other containers.

Answer (score 0):

The library sly.js fullfills everything that was needed
http://darsa.in/sly/.
The horizontal scroll behaviour works in any container on the site.

I updated the JSFiddle to work with that library.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wgLdeLnv/3/)

```
var sly = new Sly( frame, options [, callbackMap ] );
```

It's not in vanilla JS, but it works pretty well, even on mobile browser with touch and is easy to use with usefull events such as active

```
sly.on('active', function (eventName) {
    //do Something if an element got activated
});
```